# Ezpay : csrf token not allowed in header, Laravel application

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have included `<script> $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } }); </script>` in the layout blade. 
In the checkout process all steps require csrf token in the post request. But tokenisation process

```
 EZPAY.API.tokenizeForm(form)
 .done(onSuccessfulTokenize)
  .fail(onFailedTokenize)
```

in the last step showing this error

> Failed to load
>   https://psp.stg.transactium.com/hps/CardToken/TokenFor?cardno=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&expiry=xxxx&amount=xxxxxxx&cvv=xxx&currency=xxx&mode=MPI&sessionkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&_=xxx:
>   Request header field csrftoken is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

All other routes are working perfectly fine with this header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving  $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });  from body tag to head tag solved the issue. I think it's because of the overiding scripts

Answer (score 0):

.ajaxSetup dosen't need to set manualy csrf header just add csrf token in the form tag.

Comment: No i have lot of forms. I want to proceed with this method

Comment: Ok then use 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content) }

Comment: "csrftoken" should replace with "X-CSRF-TOKEN" i think it would work.